# Number of possible sequences when eight distinct six-sided dice are rolled

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Assume I have $8$ dice that have different colors.
I pick one at random and roll it, and then do it for each of the remaining.
What are the total combinations?

For $8$ dice, it would be $8^6$, but because the order matters, I assume we must do permutations.

I thought it was $(8 \cdot 6)^6 + (7 \cdot 6)^6 \ldots$, but this does not seem right.

Example: colors are Red, Yellow, Orange, Green, Blue, Violet, Pink, and White
Rolled $8$ dice and they all came up 1, and the colors picked in order were 
RYOGBVPW.  This is a different result than if I did it again and each dice came up as a $1$ again but the colors were in the order RYOGBVWP.

Comment: Apply multiplication principle.  Choose the color of first die (8 options), choose the result of first die (6 options), choose the color of second die (7 options) choose result of second die (6 options), choose color of third die (6 options), choose result of third die (6 options), choose color of fourth die (5 options), etc...   multiply these together to get the total number of outcomes noting that each time a color is chosen it cannot be chosen again and every die has six numbers it could land on regardless of where in the sequence it is chosen.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

For eight D6s of different colours you'll need to do some multiplication.

Certainly there are $8!$ ways to choose the dice. Each die has six faces. So, the number of total rolls, ignoring colour, is $6^8$, while the total number of ways to arrange the colours is $8!$, so the total number of rolls is $\boxed{8! \cdot 6^8}$.

Comment: So you are saying 67 million possibilities? 40320 * 1679616 = 67722117120 ?

Comment: @user43480 67 million?  No, that's too low.  That number is actually 67 *billion*.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you. misplaced my decimal